# Rectangular background color around wrapped text

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web app and am looking for a way to show a colored background around a block of text, but in the case where the text wraps onto 2 or more lines, I only want the background to extend as far as the furthest of any of the lines of text, not as far as the edge of the container, which seems to be the default behavior.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7jb5zg4/16/) that illustrates the problem and also what I'm looking for.

Here is the simplified issue:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
 <div style="background:blue">
  wrapped and workingasdesired
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like a way to display this as such

```
*wrapped and      *      |  
*workingasdesired *      |
```

Where `|` represents the edge of the outer container, and `*` would be the highlighted area

However, what actually happens is that the highlighting extends all the way to the end of the outer container:

```
*wrapped and            *|  
*notworkingasdesired    *|
```

I've searched around on Stack Overflow and also played with the fiddle for quite a while, but haven't had any luck.

A CSS-only solution would be the holy grail, but suggestions on good ways to accomplish this with JS would also be great!

Comment: It extends full width is because if the text have not wrapped, it would of taken the entire width so it renders as full width. If you had line breaks in the text then it would display as you desire without defined width. However, putting line breaks in text is most likely not desirable